# Бесплатный хостинг node.js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

я являюсь веб-разработчиком, на данный момент пишу полноценный чат, использую для бэкенда node.js, и СУБД MongoDB, решил потестировать как будет выглядеть чат с разных устройств. Короче решил потестировать чат. И я решил найти бесплатный хостинг MongoDB и Node.js, думал Heroku подойдёт, но насколько я слышал там прекращена поддержка MongoDB, можете пожалуйста посоветовать какой нибудь хостинг с поддержкой MongoDB и Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом MongoDB можно развернуть базу данных [Cloud MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/try), а для NodeJS либо на локальной машине либо на Heroku.

Comment: я уже пытался использовать Cloud MongoDB, но я заметил, что он очень долго отдаёт данные, а мне необходимо чтобы в 2-3 секунды приходил ответ от сервера.

Comment: поддерживаю ответ @Happy_Sweetice

Comment: @Владислав или быстро, или бесплатно. но вообще скорость ответа там была куда быстрее, чем 2-3 секунды на запрос. так что что-то не так в другом месте, скорее всего

Comment: @nörbörnën ну, может быть. Ибо я замечал что есть проблемы с интернетом сегодня.